Excel VBA error 438 calling Adobe Acrobat Pro DC Javascript
I got stumped on the attached VBA code trying to pass a javascript string from VBA to Adobe. The javascript "jsobject.app.alert" message executes fine and pops up in Adobe, but the "jsobject.ExecuteJS jsScript" line does not execute and throws error message 438. ChatGPT has got me this far, but I can't seem to get past this error. I have the latest versions of Excel Pro and Adobe Acrobat DC installed and I have tried on both 32-bit and 64-bit machines. I have tested the jscript string in the Acrobat javascript console and it works fine. Any help would be appreciated. https://imgur.com/a/9lQQNAu
Sub AddTextToPDF()
    Dim acroApp As Object
    Dim acroAVDoc As Object
    Dim acroPDDoc As Object
    Dim jsObject As Object
    Dim pdfPath As String
    Dim jsScript As String
    ' Path to the PDF file
    pdfPath = "E:\test.pdf"
    ' Check if the PDF file exists
    If Dir(pdfPath) = "" Then
        MsgBox "PDF file not found: " & pdfPath, vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Create an Acrobat application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set acroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
    Set acroAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If acroApp Is Nothing Or acroAVDoc Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Adobe Acrobat is not installed or not available.", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' Open the PDF file
    If acroAVDoc.Open(pdfPath, "") Then
        ' Get the PDDoc object from the AVDoc
        Set acroPDDoc = acroAVDoc.GetPDDoc
        ' Get the JavaScript object
        Set jsObject = acroPDDoc.GetJSObject
        'jsObject.app.alert "JavaScript is enabled and working!"  ' this code is working
        ' JavaScript to add a text annotation
        jsScript = "this.addAnnot({type: 'Text', page: 0, rect: [100, 500, 200, 550], contents: 'Finally, it works!'});"
        ' Execute the JavaScript
        jsObject.ExecuteJS jsScript
        ' Save the changes to the PDF
        acroPDDoc.Save &H1, pdfPath ' &H1 indicates incremental save
        MsgBox "Text annotation added successfully!", vbInformation, "Success"
        ' Close the PDF
        acroAVDoc.Close True
    Else
        MsgBox "Failed to open the PDF file.", vbExclamation, "Error"
    End If
    
    ' Quit Acrobat
    acroApp.Exit
    Set acroPDDoc = Nothing
    Set acroAVDoc = Nothing
    Set acroApp = Nothing
    Set jsObject = Nothing
End Sub

I have the latest versions of Excel Pro and Adobe Acrobat DC installed and I have tried on both 32-bit and 64-bit machines. I have tested the jscript string in the Acrobat javascript console and it works fine. Any help would be appreciated.

this.addAnnot - possibly its not the same "this" as what you get when typing into the console.

Just a guess, try jsObject.console.println(jsScript)

Hmm I am not using acrobat but if I run that code twice I did not notice that although said it ran it "looks" like it added two comments that I did not see until modified by flatten ! usually an appearances instruction may be needed for such objects to be visible so save and see if they appear in reader
